# XCOPY hosts file on vista from a batch file

Tags: windows-vista, xcopy, hosts-file

I need a command to replace the hosts file on my machine. Seems pretty straight forward but I cannot get the command to work with xcopy. Any obvious flaws in the command?

luaexec -w -f "XCOPY" "%ScriptPath%/ModifiedHosts/vista/hosts" 
"%windir%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts" /H

The /R flag does not seem to help and the error I get is "Error: ShellExecuteEx failed 0x2" if I remove all quotes but the beginning and end quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get any error?

Try this:

```
luaexec -w -f "XCOPY %ScriptPath%/ModifiedHosts/vista/hosts %windir%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts" /H
```

Also, you can try robocopy.

Answer (score 0):

is the hosts file write protected? it probably is..  add a /R to your commandline

Answer (score 0):

On Vista, you need to run as Administrator to change the hosts file.

[Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20201217211137/http://geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/archive/2006/12/13/changingyourhostsfileinvista.aspx)